# No bean of PatternLayoutEncoder type can be found

Tags: spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

I'm using LogBack in a Spring Boot 2 application and I'm trying to configure a console appender but it gives me the following error:

```
Description:

Parameter 1 of method consoleAppender in com.thalasoft.user.rest.config.LogWeb required a bean of type 'ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder' in your configuration.
```

But I do have such a bean specified:

```
@Configuration
public class LogWeb {

    private final static String PATTERN = "%date %-5level [%thread] %logger{36} %m%n %rEx";

    @Bean
    public static LoggerContext loggerContext() {
        return (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public static PatternLayoutEncoder encoder (LoggerContext ctx) {
        PatternLayoutEncoder encoder = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
        encoder.setContext(ctx);
        encoder.setPattern(PATTERN);
        return encoder;
    }

    @Bean (initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public static ConsoleAppender<ILoggingEvent> consoleAppender (LoggerContext loggerContext, PatternLayoutEncoder encoder) {
        ConsoleAppender<ILoggingEvent> consoleAppender = new ConsoleAppender<ILoggingEvent>();
        consoleAppender.setContext(loggerContext);
        consoleAppender.setEncoder(encoder);
        return consoleAppender;
    }

    @Bean (initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public static FileAppender<ILoggingEvent> fileAppender(LoggerContext loggerContext, PatternLayoutEncoder encoder) throws IOException {
        RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent> fileAppender = new RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent>();
        fileAppender.setContext(loggerContext);
        fileAppender.setEncoder(encoder);
        fileAppender.setFile("build.log");
        return fileAppender;
    }

    @Bean
    public Logger registerApplicationLogger(LoggerContext loggerContext, ConsoleAppender<ILoggingEvent> consoleAppender, FileAppender<ILoggingEvent> fileAppender) throws IOException {
        Logger logger = loggerContext.getLogger("com.thalasoft.user.rest");
        logger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
        logger.addAppender(consoleAppender);
        logger.addAppender(fileAppender);
        return logger;
    }

    @Bean
    public Logger registerSpringLogger(LoggerContext loggerContext, ConsoleAppender<ILoggingEvent> consoleAppender, FileAppender<ILoggingEvent> fileAppender) throws IOException {
        Logger logger = loggerContext.getLogger("org.springframework");
        logger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
        logger.addAppender(consoleAppender);
        logger.addAppender(fileAppender);
        return logger;
    }

}
```

I'm using `Spring Boot 2.0.3`.

Comment: Why not simply use XML? And why are all your beans `static`?

Comment: Simply because I thought Spring moved from XML to java configuration. As for the static, I saw it on a blog, but removing it has no effect on the issue.

Comment: logback configuration isn't spring configuration...

Comment: All right, but this java configuration class was working fine for years. And yesterday it stopped.

Comment: Well what changed, revert and see if it works again...

Comment: Indeed, stashing it all resolves the issue. I'd have to drill down further. Meanwhile, I removed all static keywords but it has no effect on the issue. Having debugger breakpoints in all above beans, only the first one stops, the other beans are not loaded.

Comment: I assume all your configurtion above could be placed in your properties file. This should work out of the box without doing something in Java code. Wouldn't this be an option?

Comment: @Michael Exactly what I was thinking. But the curiousity in me is still itching as to why this one is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method named was the issue. After renaming the method to `patternLayoutEncoder` as in `public PatternLayoutEncoder patternLayoutEncoder(LoggerContext ctx) {` the bean was discovered and loaded all right.